# "conflicting server name "localhost"" and "broken header" error happens in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I am trying to create a new AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment from a saved configuration. The platform is Amason Linux and Ruby on Rails. The EC2 instance generated by the environment is behind a load balancer. An API server is running on the instance, our frontend web communicates with the API server through HTTP method: GET, POST, ...

In the source code of the API server, we use file `.ebextensions`. The loadbalancer part in `.exbextensions` is set as below:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: 80
          InstanceProtocol: HTTP
          LoadBalancerPort: 80
          Protocol: HTTP
      AccessLoggingPolicy:
        EmitInterval: 5
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName:
          Ref: LogsBucket
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    DependsOn: "LogsBucketPolicy"
```

and the nginx in `.exbextensions` is configured as:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
content: |
  client_max_body_size 500M;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

  upstream backend {
    server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header proxy_protocol;

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_buffers 8 32k;
      proxy_buffer_size 64k;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_redirect off;

      # Enables WebSocket support
      location /v1/cable {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
      }
    }
  }
```

In the environment configuration, the load balancer is set as below, an AWS SSL certificate is added.

[image]

After creating the environment, an instance and a load balancer are automatically created. The health status of the instance is Ok.

[image]

I open the frontend app and try to login with my account, but login failed. I check the logs of the environment, found below errors.

[image]

Everything work when I use the old environment which connect to the same AWS backends (EB workers, DB, etc). It seems something wrong in the configuration of loadbalancer and network... Can you please give some ideas?

Comment: What's the difference between old and new EB platform that you are using?

Comment: @Marcin I created new EB based on the configuration of old one.